# How to make .exe to .swf?

Tags: flash, exe

I have a exe file, I wanna convert it to a swf file. When I use some "exe to swf converters" I get this error "No swf files were found" Can you guys give help me with make exe file to a swf file?

Comment: Exe is an executable, SWF is a flash file. They are not the same thing, and without a source file they are probably not directly convertible...

Comment: Oh, is it possible to convert exe to dmg?

Comment: Exe is a _windows_ executable and dmg is a unix _disk image_ - just from that description I'd say no. But I'm no expert...